# Install Handler in Equinox P2

Tags: eclipse, plugins, installation, handler, equinox

I'm writing plugin for eclipse 3.6 and need to make changes in external files during plugin installation process. In org.eclipse.core.updates there was an IInstallHandler interface which was used for alternating of install process. How can I do my install handler with new Equinox P2 system?